# Why name lookup can't find std::swap when a base class has a swap function in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, argument-dependent-lookup, name-lookup

I have a replica of what's inside my code

```
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

class Parent
{
    public:
        void swap(Parent*);
};
class A : public Parent 
{
    public:
        void handle();
};


void A::handle()
{

    long x = 1;
    long y = 2;
    swap(x,y);
}


int main()
{
    A v;
    v.handle();
    return 0;
}
```

The error log:

```
main.cpp: In member function 'void A::handle()':
main.cpp:21:10: error: no matching function for call to 'A::swap(long int&, long int&)'
  swap(x,y);
          ^
main.cpp:7:8: note: candidate: void Parent::swap(Parent*)
   void swap(Parent*);
        ^
main.cpp:7:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
```

To my understanding `swap` call inside `A::handle()` will trigger non-qualified lookup and because it will find swap name in the parent class that's a function, argument-dependent name lookup (ADL) will be called.
Why the ADL here can't find the `std::swap` and use it ? Instead it tries to call the Parent's swap.

What I am missing here ?

---

Platform/Compiler: Red hat 6.7/ GNU 5.3.0

Platform/Compiler: Windows 10/ visual studio 2015

Comment: ADL does not work with fundamental types. `long` is not from `std::`

Comment: Regarding the error: Do you _have_ an overload matching `A::swap(long int&, long int&)`?

Comment: Firstly, the compiler looks in the closest containing scope (in this case, `A` and then its bases, before looking in the global scope) for the name.   It finds `Parent::swap()`.   Then, due to the hiding rule, this hides candidate `swap()` functions in containing scopes.    All this happens before it attempts to determine if arguments match types for the candidates it finds.   To resolve, either call `std::swap()` unambiguously (i.e. `std::swap(x,y)` instead of `swap(x,y)`) or remove `Parent::swap()`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, No. This all the code I have.

Comment: @ShadyAtef But, you see that the compiler is trying to match against it. That's a huge hint!

Comment: @TedLyngmo, I see this, I am trying to understand the ADL related part. I understand I can use fully-qualified call to `std::swap`.

Comment: How do you expect a function that takes a `Parent *` as its only argument to be called with two `long` values?

Comment: @ShadyAtef Doesn't any of the answers provide info enough? (edit: oh, only one answer is left - it's good though)

Comment: @TedLyngmo, Ofcourse a lot of answers are here, but I was trying to wrap my head around it. 
Yeah, a sole answer, he is lucky gaining a good reputation points.

Thank you for your time

Comment: @ShadyAtef  Thanks and I'm glad you found a solution to the problem!

Comment: I voted to reopen this question because it's intentional and reproducible.

Comment: @Peter "*To resolve, either call `std::swap()` unambiguously (i.e. `std::swap(x,y)` instead of `swap(x,y)`) or remove `Parent::swap()`*" - 3rd option, add `using std::swap;` inside of `void A::handle()` , then `swap(x,y);` will use `std::swap()` if `Parent::swap()` is not a match for the arguments. [demo](https://ideone.com/a34DhB)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For [unqualified name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup):

> name lookup examines the scopes as described below, until it finds at least one declaration of any kind, at which time the lookup stops and no further scopes are examined.

So the name `swap` is examined in class `A` firstly, it's not found, then examined in class `Parent`, it's found, then name lookup stops. `std::swap` introduced into global scope won't be found at all.

And

> Why the ADL here can't find the `std::swap` and use it ?

You're passing `long`s to `swap`, while [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) works with class types, but not fundamental types.

> 1. For arguments of fundamental type, the associated set of namespaces and classes is empty

BTW: In this special case even you change to pass some class types defined in `std` namespace to `swap` ADL won't be considered either.

> First, the argument-dependent lookup is not considered if the lookup set produced by usual unqualified lookup contains any of the following:
>
> 1. a declaration of a class member

`Parent::swap` is a class member which is found by usual unqualified name lookup, ADL still won't be considered.

Comment: To my understanding, If the found name is function, ADL will be invoked. If this right, it should find the one in std

Comment: @ShadyAtef `long` is not a member of `std`, so no ADL.  ADL works with types and functions that are declared in the same namespace.

Comment: @ShadyAtef - All that sonyuanyao describes happens BEFORE the compiler even checks types of arguments i.e. before ADL comes into play.

Comment: @ShadyAtef Answer revised.

Comment: @songyuanyao, Thank you. Now it's more clear.

Comment: @ShadyAtef Additional information added, it might be helpful.